# What is the problem with the following SQL query corresponding to the described problem below?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

**Create the Shopper table with appropriate data types for the attributes described below.**

Column Name     Constraints     Description of the attributes are given as follows ----

Shopperid       PRIMARY KEY     Unique id of the shopper. For ex. 2001, 2003
ShopperName     NOT NULL        Name of the Shopper. It cannot be more than 20         characters.
Gender                          Should be only 'Male' or 'Female'   Gender of the Shopper. It cannot be more than 6 characters.
MobileNo        NOT NULL        Mobile number of the Shopper in numeric form. Characters like brackets and hyphens are not allowed.
Address                         Address of the Shopper. It cannot be more than 50 characters. For ex. Allen Street, New York

```
create table shopper(shopperid integer primary key, shoppername varchar2(20) not null, gender varchar2(6) check (gender in ('Male', 'Female')), mobileno number(10) not null, address varchar2(50));
```

But the portal where I am practicing is giving me this message ----
**Error: Your query did not meet the requirement. Please check data types.**

Can anyone please help me out what things I am missing? Any kind of help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @forpas Yes, I am using Oracle 11g Express Edition database. I tried to add that tag but couldn't as it requires at least 1500 reputations!

Comment: Is the semi-colon at the end of the CREATE TABLE necessary?  Some tools (unlike SQL*Plus and SQL*Developer) don't like terminating semi-colons and can give misleading errors when they find one.

Comment: @cdub it's not but the problem is somewhere regarding the data types I am using. They are wanting something different. But where the difference lies I can't trace it out myself.

Comment: The error suggests that the problem is with the data types, but the actual problem might be due to something else.  Have you tried creating the table without the constraints?  If that still errors out, then how about just creating a table with a single column and no constraints?  Does any of this work?  You could start with trying to create the most basic table and then gradually add in more columns and constraints until you find the error.

Comment: @cdub It will not work because creating the table with a single attribute or without constraints will still say that the requirements are not getting fulfilled as they only show 'Congratulations! Your query worked correctly.' upon completing the task 100% correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure why it got down-voted (wasn't me).  Last thoughts: (1) mobileno is defined as NUMBER(10), but the requirements don't explicitly state a scale of 10. Maybe try using just "NUMBER" instead of "NUMBER(10)"; (2) the tool may not  recognize INTEGER as a valid type. INTEGER is much less common in Oracle than NUMBER. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that might be wrong is phone number. Currently, it allows something like this:

```
SQL> create table shopper
  2    (shopperid   integer primary key,
  3     shoppername varchar2(20) not null,
  4     gender      varchar2(6) check (gender in ('Male', 'Female')),
  5     mobileno    number(10) not null,
  6     address     varchar2(50)
  7    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into shopper (shopperid, shoppername, gender, mobileno, address) values
  2    (1, 'x', 'Male', 0.0013, 'y');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

What kind of a mobile number would 0.0013 be? Probably should have been **integer**.

Comment: That's correct but I have also tried with integer but it raised the same error. I checked multiple times with various combinations but not a single worked. That's why I am asking for help from you adepts.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with syntax (otherwise table wouldn't be created). I don't see anything wrong (regarding task you've been given) either. As far as I'm concerned, you did it correctly (apart from the phone number).

Comment: No problem; let us know what went wrong, if you ever find it out.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE Shopper(
ShopperId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(6) CHECK (Gender IN('Male', 'Female')),
MobileNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR2(50)
)

THE ABOVE SYNTAX WORKED FOR ME.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of the column GENDER is the problem, change VARCHAR2(6) to CHAR(6) to  then it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table shopper
     (shopperid   integer primary key,
      shoppername varchar2(20) not null,
      gender      char(6) check (gender in ('Male', 'Female')),
      mobileno    integer not null,
      address     varchar2(50)
     );
```

It will work without error

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your SQL Query but the portal accepts the answer only if the datatype of the column "Shopperid" is NUMBER.

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper(
  Shopperid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  Gender CHAR(6) CHECK(GENDER IN ('Male', 'Female')),
  MobileNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR2(50)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
create table shopper (
  shopperid number primary key, 
  shopperName varchar(20) not null, 
  gender char(6), 
  Mobileno number not null, 
  Address varchar(50), 
  CONSTRAINT CHK_Gender check(GENDER in ('Male', 'Female'))
);
```

Comment: A good answer always includes an explanation of how it solves the issue, so that any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: This answer is very similar to [another answer[(https://stackoverflow.com/a/56689295/840340) and as noted above doesn't contain explanation and answer to the question.